# Updating mouse cursor while cursor is down OpenGl/Glut

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have been writing a rudimentary code using the OpenGL and Glut Libraries that prints out the mouse location while it is in the window. I have been using glutMousefunc() to update the coordinate. However one problem I came across was that the mouse cursor location stops updating while the mouse is held down.

Here is an extremely barebones pseudocode version of my program

```
double mx1, my1; // These are the coordinates of the mouse

void mouse(int button, int state, int mx, int my)
{
mx1 = mx;
my1 = my;
}
void idle(void) // GLUT calls this function in a continuous loop
{
 printf("%lf, %lf",mx1, my1);
.......}
void main()
{....
  glutMouseFunc(mouse);
...}
```

How should I update my mouse cursor location while the mouse is being held down? Thank you for all of your help in advance!! Let me know if any further clarification is needed!

Comment: `glutMouseFunc` is setting the callback function*once*. It shouldn't be called in a loop. And the callback is called only when mouse button event is happening. I suggest you to read more in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had the glutmousefunc in main, but I didn't want to over complicate the code snippet so in my sample I mistakenly put it in the idle.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: [`glutMotionFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html)